# "Destroying of world" or "Destroying world"?

Tags: prepositions, tense, prepositional-phrases, verb-forms

For meaning like "world destroying" or "destruction of world". What form should be used? What are their names, because in grammar rules of participle tense forms there are absolutely different examples compared to my goals here in creating: nouns, or concepts, or situations (phenomena), or options (like option A and option B (like not destroying world))? Also in my research there are both such forms in web articles if to search literally with quotes, but their meaning is strange and not understandable

Comment: Meaning is about "the world" or other objects, it's about nouns or mentioned stuff and not adjectives. Like it's about "destroying the world" by someone or something and not some destroying everything and other worlds world

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what your question is or what you are needing help with.  Can you rephrase your question to say (1) what you are trying to do and (2) what the actual problem was that you ran into?  Also, do you have any examples of similar things you have found which might help understand the problem?

Comment: @Foogod Problem in using some participle tense (with "ing") nouns or concepts with prepositions (like "of") in ways like in that example (with saying "destroying of the world" while trying to transmit meaning of "world destruction"), because it looks very strange either way of using them, and I cannot find grammar on that and there are examples in literal quotation search for both ways. About the concepts that could be rarely used in common talking, imagine having activities to do or goals in schedule as "practicing of that programming language for 2 hours" or "learning of English language"